# Cannot checkout branch or remove problematic files

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge, git-checkout

I have 2 branches in my Java project: master and refactor. I've finished working on refactor so now would like to `checkout master` and merge refactor into master. While working on the refactor, I also added some files to .gitignore (one of them was .idea) and now I get:

```
[michal@michal-pc MCleaner]$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
.idea/description.html
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/project-template.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I've read many posts  and nothing works. How can I remove those files without accessing master branch? Is there a way to fix that? Please provide cmd commands if you can, I'm still new to git.

Here is the output from `git status`:

```
On branch refactor
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/refactor'.

Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  .idea/
  target/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Have you commited all updates to your refactor branch?

Comment: Yes, here is git status:
    `michal@michal-pc MCleaner]$ git status
    On branch refactor
    Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/refactor'.
    Untracked files:
      (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .idea/
 target/
      nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to        track)

`

Comment: Then the .idea directory is *not* commited as it is still untracked. Throw it out or add it. - depending on whether its part of your project or was just a temporary space for you.

Comment: It's part of my project (IntelliJ files) but I don't want it to be added to my repo (or github for that matter)

Comment: They seem to be on your master branch though since the checkout claims to overwrite them.

Comment: One more question, did you really add .idea to your local .gitignore file?

Comment: Hard remove those untracked file doesn't really solve the problem here, they might still come back.

Comment: @Xlee Answer by Roman down below solved my problem. Why wouldn't I add .idea to .gitignore? Those files arent essential to a project shared on GitHub, are they?

Comment: Im just interested if they're on the blacklist of git(declared in gitignore), why git still care about them, gitignore is simply for ignoring those untracked files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to `.gitignore`

```
.idea
```

and remove this directory

```
git rm -r .idea
```

Then commit changes.

Comment: @Andreas_D I was mistaken, I only added some files from .idea not whole folder to .gitignore. Works great now!

Answer (score 11):

First run

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

The result will be something like the following

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/codeStyles/Project.xml
        .idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

If you're ok to lose any data in those files (**THEY WILL BE OVERWRITTEN**) go ahead and run

```
git checkout <branch_name> --force
```

Comment: This fixed the issue - one small note is that the command should be.   

`git checkout <branch_name> --force`

Answer (score 1):

Add these files which you do not wish to track in the **`.gitignore`** file.

As a best practice, you should only be tracking your source code and resources files specific for your project. IDE project specific settings files should not be tracked and committed.
By doing this, the project becomes IDE agnostic and any developer will be able to checkout the repo and work seamlessly irrespective of any IDE he chooses.

Example: Add these in the **`.gitignore`** file

```
.idea         #intellij files
.settings     #eclipse files
```

Note: Similarly add other IDE settings directories like this.

Then commit the changes.

If the files are currently in the remote repo, then delete those files before you commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual of

```
git clean --help
```